# Alternatives - I am successful now "thanks to" my friend

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to ask which words can be used instead of ***thanks to*** in such as sentences that carry affirmative connotation as in the following.

> I am successful now ***thanks to*** my friend, who has been always kind to
>   me.

Especially what I am asking is which ones are suitable for affirmative sentences : owing to, due to, because of,for the sake of, on account of or other words

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*For the sake of* means something different (that you became successful for your friend's benefit). Your other options all mean roughly the same thing as *thanks to* in this context.

Other than *thanks to*, I'd say *on account of* carries the most positive connotation.

Comment: Thanks..so it is about context ?

Comment: What is about context? The positive connotation?

Comment: I would not be suprised if I hear : I was failed because of you , but does it sound ok if someone says  " I was successful at the exam because of you"

Comment: yes the positive connotation

Comment: Yes it does. In my opinion, *owing to*, *due to*, and *because of* are neutral. They just state that one thing helped cause the other.

*Thanks to* connotes positivity, like thanking someone for the help. You could say “I failed, thanks to you” but I would say that's a sarcastic usage.

*On account of* is also mostly neutral, I think. You could say “We had to close the business on account of bad investments” or “The business succeeded on account of good investments.”

These are all based on what I think when I hear them, so yes, it's definitely about context and maybe some personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

I am successful now because of my friend. The other words like owing to, on account of etc., needs some other words to fill the sentence.